# Execute ELF Kernel file from FAT12 Bootlader

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm, freepascal, bootloader

I am seeking on run ELF kernel builded with freepascal but when I try to call it with fat12 bootloader (0x1000) it halts.  Can anyone give me a code example about how to run it?

[Here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Pascal_Bare_Bones)  is what I tried to make.

Also, I am working on Windows.  I should not use grub.  I have to make my own bootloader.  I just need a code example about how to run this operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "kernel" you linked is specifically designed to work with [MultiBoot 1](http://wiki.osdev.org/Multiboot) bootloaders, read this as *specifically designed to work with GRUB*.

In order to make a bootloader able to load it you need to comply with those specifications and possibly be ready to understand some of the ELF format.

You could try to make the minimal working environment for that kernel but would it be faster to actually rewrite that tiny piece of kernel software by your own?

That kernel is meant to be used with GRUB, you either rewrite a GRUB or rewrite the kernel.
I'd personally go for the latter, rewriting a MultiBoot 1 compatible bootloader will take a lot of time and effort for a simple kernel of that.